# No internet connection after update 12.04

Tags: networking

I updated 12.04 and then not able to connect to internet via firefox or thunderbird email.

It is a wired connection.

ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e6:fc:85:0b:63  
          inet6 addr: fe80::56e6:fcff:fe85:b63/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4713 (4.7 KB)  TX bytes:5004 (5.0 KB) 
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc00 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:a4:69:33  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) 
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0xe000 

eth1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:a4:69:33  
          inet addr:169.254.5.249  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0 
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0xe000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:13074 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:13074 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1059344 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1059344 (1.0 MB)
```

And lspci:

```
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Host Bridge (rev a1) 
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2) 
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2) 
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2) 
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3) 
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3) 
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1) 
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2) 
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2) 
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2) 
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) 
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) 
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) 
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) 
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) 
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] (rev a2) 
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration 
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map 
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller 
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control 
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control 
01:08.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10) 
bill@bill-desktop:~$
```

Comment: ifconfig output please?

Comment: to help you whe need more information: You are using Cable Network or Wireless Lan?
Please give us the Output from "ifconfig" and "lspci"
Whe must now the configuration and your network- Hardware. If you can not do this, check ubuntu live- if it runs then rescue your data and install new. If not, come Back to here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a number of places:
Open the file /etc/resolv.com
(you can use a terminal and enter **sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf**)

add a line **nameserver 8.8.8.8** #This adds a google dns

However, this solution is not permanant, as it seems to be overwritten with certain updates...